# how to fix text overlay - Python

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Please tell me how to fix this code so that there are no text overlays

```
from tkinter import *
x = Tk()
x.geometry('100x100')

def button():
    if btn['text'] == 'btn1':
        btn['text'] = 'btn2'
        label = Label(x, text="12", font=("Times",15)).place(x=5, y=5)
    elif btn['text'] == 'btn2':
        btn["text"] = 'btn3'
        label = Label(x, text="12345", font=("Times",15)).place(x=5, y=5)
    else:
        btn["text"] = 'btn1'
        label = Label(x, text="543", font=("Times", 15)).place(x=5, y=5)  
btn = Button(x, text='btn1', command = lambda: button())
btn.place(x=30, y=30)   
x.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you using same place value for each label?

Comment: I need data to be output in one place

Comment: How they should look like? can you tell that also like positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do that,is just changing text in label, not creating new label each time when you press the button:

```
from tkinter import *
x = Tk()
x.geometry('100x100')

def button():
    if btn['text'] == 'btn1':
        btn['text'] = 'btn2'
        label['text']="12"
    else:
        btn["text"] = 'btn1'
        label['text']="12345"

label = Label(x, text="", font=("Times",15))
label.place(x=5, y=5)
btn = Button(x, text='btn1', command = lambda: button())
btn.place(x=30, y=30)

x.mainloop()
```